# Crystal installation on WSL fails

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, crystal-lang

I'm following the current crystal installation docs, my installation stops at the first moment and give the error:

`gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.4GKHZljOFL/S.dirmngr' failed: IPC connect call failed
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr`

I've already installed dirmngr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to remove crystal.list from sources directory to install from start manually.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/crystal.list
```

And then:

```
curl -s "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x09617FD37CC06B54" | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dist.crystal-lang.org/apt crystal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/crystal.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install crystal
```