# sbt installation on WSL Fails

Tags: scala, sbt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install `sbt` on Windows subsystem for Linux from [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html). Following is my bash terminal output:

```
username:repo$ echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /
username:repo$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.NbSR0JqpKB/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.NbSR0JqpKB/S.dirmngr' failed: IPC connect call failed
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

I have checked that `dirmngr` is installed. 'sudo apt-get update` gives following output:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Ign:4 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease
Get:5 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release [815 B]
Get:6 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release.gpg [821 B]
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Ign:6 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 99E82A75642AC823
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Output of `sudo apt-get install sbt`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sbt
```

I have looked at [this similar question about installing `crystal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990195/crystal-installation-on-wsl-fails) but don't know how to apply the solution to this situation.

Answer (score 5):

It is a WSL bug, see this [workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3286#issuecomment-395980867).

You only need to change the Hexadecimal value. So for SBT it would be:

```
curl -sL "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823" | sudo apt-key add
```

**PS**: Note this command is intended to replace the following command

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
```

As you can see, both Hexadecimal values are the same. *(Except that in the first one you prepend it with `0x` which is used to indicate the following is a decimal value)*.
So, this workaround can be applied to any key.

Comment: I tried your cammand. Still getting the same error about `dirmngr`. I also removed the `sbt.list` file beforehand. Still same error.

Comment: Hi @dc95, I have just uninstalled and reinstalled sbt from my WSL and it worked, I removed the package file and the key before reinstalling it from scratch.

Did you get an `OK` as the output of my command?, and if type `sudo apt-key list` can you see a line like this in the output: **sbt build tool <scalasbt@gmail.com>**